# Proving an equality using the Leibniz integral rule.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f:[0,b]\times [0,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, proof 
$\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}x\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} y\right)
=
\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\left(\int_{y}^{b}f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} x\right)$ using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

It is easy to verify this equality by other means. But I can not see how the differentiation under the integral sign can be applied to verify this equality.

**Proofs without using the Leibniz integral rule.**

**First proof.**  Note that $
\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}x\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} y\right)
$
and
$
\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\left(\int_{y}^{b}f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} x\right)
$
are identical  to 
$$
\mathop{\int\int}_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq y\leq x\leq b\}} f(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}\; A
$$

**Second proof.**  For all polynomial function 
$p(x,y)=c_{0,0}+c_{0,1}y^{1}+c_{0,1}x^{1}+c_{1,1}x^{1}y^{1}+\ldots+c_{n,m}x^ny^m $
it is easy to verify that
$
\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}x\left(\int_{0}^{x}p(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} y\right)
=
\int_{0}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\left(\int_{y}^{b}p(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} x\right).
$
To complete the proof we use the Weierstrass approximation theorem ( or Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 \le t \le b$ define
$$
 g(t) = \int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} y\right)
 - \int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}y\left(\int_{y}^{t}f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} x\right) \, .
$$
Then $g(0) = 0$ and
$$
 g'(t) = \left[\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} y\right]_{x=t}
 - \left( \left[\int_{y}^{t}f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d} x\right]_{y=t}
 + \int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}y \, \bigl[ f(x, y)\bigr]_{x=t} \right) \\
= \int_{0}^{t}f(t,y)\, \mathrm{d} y 
 - \left( \int_{t}^{t}f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{0}^{t} f(t, y) \mathrm{d}y \right)= 0
$$
and therefore $g(b) = 0$, which is the desired identity.